# Can the entire screen be filtered with a Core Image filter?

Tags: macos, screen

(edited for SO): Under OS X (any release), is it possible to apply Core Image filters to the entire screen? If so, what are the relevant functions, classes or methods (or appropriate section of the documentation), to get started?

I've been digging through Apple's Core Image documentation, but haven't made much progress towards this particular goal.

Comment: This would be better suited to Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Philip: I was looking for separate programmatic and non-programmatic answers (even if the non-programmatic answer was a simple "No."), but the questions can be merged if others don't mind conflating the two (ever since the Barque trilogy, I want to use ["confuse"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=confuse) in the old sense, but that would just be confusing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is *yes*, you can apply a filter to the whole screen, but only through code, example: [Nocturne](http://code.google.com/p/blacktree-nocturne/wiki/Nocturne).

But there’s no “AU Lab” for CodeImage that I know off.

Comment: [That](http://code.google.com/p/blacktree-nocturne/source/browse/trunk/QSCIFilterWindow.m)'ll do it.